# How do i pass a control(Button,...) reference from Labview to C#(VisualStudio)

Tags: c#, labview

i have a button on my FrontPanel in LabView. I created a DLL in VisualStudio that i would like to use in Labview to get the coordinates of that button.

```
    public void GetCoords(Control ctr, out Point p)
    {
        Point location = ctr.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
        p = location;
    }
```

My GetCoords method uses a "Control" input parameter which is my button in LabView. When i link my button reference from Labview to the method from C# using the DLL i get an error that my reference from my control in labview is not a .NET reference. And yes, its not a .NET control, but what do i use in C# instead of "Control" parameter so i can input my labview control?

So is there any other way to send my Labview button reference to the C# DLL ?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I believe that isn't possible. But, I think that a possible solution, is to create a wrapper of LabVIEW Control (using another Value Object from .NET). Best regards.

Comment: It might help if we could understand why you want to do this - do you really need the coordinates or do you actually want to operate the control? Can you make changes to the LabVIEW code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the way you want to do it is the best way. If you want the coordinates of the control, just get those coordinates in LabVIEW.

Look at this article: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019S7gSAE&l=en-US

IF you need to you can then pass the specific coordinates to the C# code. But the C# code does not need your control reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct mechanism. You would need to pass the control ref to your C# code, then have the C# code call back into LabVIEW to do operations. It works best if your G code* is a DLL and the C# code calls in to get the ref and then calls in again to get info about the ref. If you try to have G call out to C#, and then want the C# to call back, it’s really complicated to structure.

*G=graphical